# AsyncStorage.getItem takes 500ms

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I store the tokens of my users in AsyncStorage.

On app load, I wait for AsyncStorage.getItem to retrieve the token.

This step always takes more than 150ms. It often takes 500ms.

This has an impact on app loading time and I would like to decrease this time significantly.

I use https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage in its latest version (1.12.0) and React Native 0.60.6. This problem occurs on Android.

Do you know if this is normal? The figures in https://medium.com/@Sendbird/extreme-optimization-of-asyncstorage-in-react-native-b2a1e0107b34 seem to indicate that this is not normal.

Do you know what could be the cause of the issue please?

Comment: Are you sure that AsyncStorage is taking 500ms or is it something else? how did you test this and how many Items do you usally want to get back from AStorage?

Comment: I only want to get one element back from AsyncStorage. I tested it by putting `t = Date.now()` just before the read from AsyncStorage, and doing a console.log of `Date.now() - t` just after.